Why is Azure REST API create/update index unsucessful when using vectorSearch on a field
I have a deployment script run in Azure as part of a BICEP file. The deployement script sends a API request to create the AISearchService index which is sucessful.
The problems is that none of the ressource defined in the request body vectorSearch or semantic element are created when looking at the AISearchService in the Azure Portal.
The script will also fail if the index has a field refering to a vectorSearch profile (since the profile does not exist).
I am using the 2024-05-01-preview REST API version as I am trying to use the AIStudio embedding model deployment. My goal is to replicate the portal index & vectorize button using integrated vectorization feature of the AISearchService index.
Request body defined in PS deployment script:
    'name' = $indexBaseName;
    'fields' = @(
        @{ 'name' = 'chunk_id'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'analyzer' = 'keyword'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $true };
        @{ 'name' = 'parent_id'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false };
        @{ 'name' = 'chunk'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false; };
        @{ 'name' = 'title'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false; };
        @{ 'name' = 'metadata_storage_path'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false; };
    );
    'similarity' = @{
        '@odata.type' = '#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity';
        'k1' = $null;
        'b' = $null;
    };
    'semantic' = @{
        'configurations' = @(
            @{ 
                'name' = $indexBaseName + '-semantic-configuration';
                'prioritizedFields' = @{ 
                    'titleField' = @{ 'fieldName' = 'title';};
                    'prioritizedContentFields' = @( @{ 'fieldName' = 'content';}; );
                }; 
            };
        );
    };
    'vectorSearch' = @{
        'profiles' = @( 
            @{
                'name' = $indexBaseName+'profile';
                'algorithm' = $indexBaseName+'-algorithm';
            };
        );
        'algorithms' = @(
            @{ 
                'name' = $indexBaseName+'-algorithm'; 
                'kind' = 'hnsw';
                'hnswParameters' = @{
                    'metric' = 'cosine';
                    'm' = 4;
                    'efConstruction' = 400;
                    'efSearch' = 500;
                };
            };
        );
        'compressions' = @(
            @{
                'name' = $indexBaseName+'-compression';
                'kind' = 'scalarQuantization';
                'rerankWithOriginalVectors' = $true;
                'defaultOversampling' = 10.0;
                'scalarQuantizationParameters' = @{
                    'quantizedDataType' = 'int8';
                };
            };
        );
        'vectorizers' = @(
            @{
                'name' = $indexBaseName+'-vectorizer'; 
                'kind' = 'aml';
                'amlParameters' = @{ 
                    'key' = 'XXXXX';
                    'modelName' = 'text-embedding-ada-002';
                    'uri' = $aiServiceRessourceId;
                };
            };
        );
    };
};

Deployment script output:
Setup Azure Search Service rag-rfp-searchservice starting...
Using Ai Service resource id https://canadaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/openai/deployments/text-embedding-ada-002/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15
Shoul match format subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace-name}/onlineendpoints/{endpoint_name}
[33;1mWARNING: Upcoming breaking changes in the cmdlet 'Get-AzAccessToken' :
The Token property of the output type will be changed from String to SecureString. Add the [-AsSecureString] switch to avoid the impact of this upcoming breaking change.
- The change is expected to take effect in Az version : '13.0.0'
- The change is expected to take effect in Az.Accounts version : '4.0.0'
Note : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.[0m
Data source type: azureblob
Creating Index azureblob-vectorized-index
Creating Index System.Collections.Hashtable
[33;1mWARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.[0m

[32;1mStatusCode        : [0m201
[32;1mStatusDescription : [0mCreated
[32;1mContent           : [0m{"@odata.context":"https://rag-rfp-searchservice.search.win
                    [32;1m[0mdows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity","@odata.etag":"\"0x8DCC
                    [32;1m[0m3917D225648\"","name":"azureblob-vectorized-index","default
                    [32;1m[0mScoringProfile":null,"f…
[32;1mRawContent        : [0mHTTP/1.1 201 Created
[32;1m                    [0mTransfer-Encoding: chunked
[32;1m                    [0mETag: "0x8DCC3917D225648"
[32;1m                    [0mLocation: https://rag-rfp-searchservice.search.windows.net/
                    [32;1m[0mindexes('azureblob-vectorized-index')?api-version=2024-05-0
                    [32;1m[0m1-previe…
[32;1mHeaders           : [0m{[Transfer-Encoding, System.String[]], [ETag, 
                    [32;1m[0mSystem.String[]], [Location, System.String[]], [Server, 
                    [32;1m[0mSystem.String[]]…}
[32;1mImages            : [0m{}
[32;1mInputFields       : [0m{}
[32;1mLinks             : [0m{}
[32;1mRawContentLength  : [0m2188
[32;1mRelationLink      : [0m{}

JSON of search index whne viewed in portal:
  "@odata.context": "https://rag-rfp-searchservice.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DCC3917D225648\"",
  "name": "azureblob-vectorized-index",
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "chunk_id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "parent_id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "chunk",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "title",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "stored": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "vectorEncoding": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": {
    "defaultConfiguration": null,
    "configurations": []
  },
  "vectorSearch": {
    "algorithms": [],
    "profiles": [],
    "vectorizers": [],
    "compressions": []
  }
}

Here is the result when using an index with an index field using a vectorSearchProfile.
Request body defined in PS deployment script:
    'name' = $indexBaseName2;
    'fields' = @(
        @{ 'name' = 'chunk_id'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'analyzer' = 'keyword'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $true };
        @{ 'name' = 'parent_id'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false };
        @{ 'name' = 'chunk'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false };
        @{ 'name' = 'title'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false };
        @{ 'name' = 'metadata_storage_path'; 'type' = 'Edm.String'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true; 'filterable' = $true; 'sortable' = $true; 'facetable' = $true; 'key' = $false };
        @{ 'name' = 'text_vector'; 'type' = 'Collection(Edm.Single)'; 'dimensions'= 1536; 'vectorSearchProfile' = $indexBaseName2+'profile'; 'retrievable' = $true; 'searchable' = $true };
    );
    'similarity' = @{
        '@odata.type' = '#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity';
        'k1' = $null;
        'b' = $null;
    };
    'semantic' = @{
        'configurations' = @(
            @{ 
                'name' = $indexBaseName2 + '-semantic-configuration';
                'prioritizedFields' = @{ 
                    'titleField' = @{ 'fieldName' = 'title'};
                    'contentFields' = @( @{ 'fieldName' = 'chunk'} );
                }; 
            };
        );
        'defaultConfiguration' = $indexBaseName2 + '-semantic-configuration';
    };
    'vectorSearch' = @{
        'algorithms' = @(
            @{ 
                'name' = $indexBaseName2+'-algorithm'; 
                'kind' = 'hnsw';
                'hnswParameters' = @{
                    'metric' = 'cosine';
                    'm' = 4;
                    'efConstruction' = 400;
                    'efSearch' = 500;
                };
            };
        );
        'vectorizers' = @(
            @{
                'name' = $indexBaseName2+'-vectorizer'; 
                'kind' = 'aml';
                'amlParameters' = @{ 
                    'key' = 'XXXXX';
                    'modelName' = 'text-embedding-ada-002';
                    'uri' = $aiServiceRessourceId;
                };
            };
        );
        'profiles' = @( 
            @{
                'name' = $indexBaseName2+'profile';
                'algorithm' = $indexBaseName2+'-algorithm';
                'vectorizer' = $indexBaseName2+'-vectorizer';
            };
        );
    };
};

Deployment script output:
Setup Azure Search Service rag-rfp-searchservice starting...
Using Ai Service resource id https://canadaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/openai/deployments/text-embedding-ada-002/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15
Shoul match format subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace-name}/onlineendpoints/{endpoint_name}
[33;1mWARNING: Upcoming breaking changes in the cmdlet 'Get-AzAccessToken' :
The Token property of the output type will be changed from String to SecureString. Add the [-AsSecureString] switch to avoid the impact of this upcoming breaking change.
- The change is expected to take effect in Az version : '13.0.0'
- The change is expected to take effect in Az.Accounts version : '4.0.0'
Note : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.[0m
Data source type: azureblob
Creating Index azureblob-vectorized-index-2
Creating Index System.Collections.Hashtable
[33;1mWARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.[0m
[33;1mWARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.[0m


The index describes and contains all data that can be searched. Every data field you want to search gets its own field in the search index. Each field also has a data type and different properties – as if the field is sortable or facetable. The index reflects the data you want to search without the unnecessary fields you do not need and is precisely customized for your search case. This means that the data can be searched a lot faster than your non-optimized data.

@Sampath I understand that these are the index responsability.
My problem is that the integrated vectorization feature is not working. Is there another route than the create/update index API route I should use to configure those?

Problem elements are not created (e.g. vectorSearch profiles/vectorizer/algorithms/compression can be resloved adding vectorSearchProfile to the fileds like this `` vectorSearchProfile = "my-vector-profile"``` and configuring the vectorSearch with algorithms and profiles. can i share the example.

@Sampath adding a field with the vectorSearchProfile makes the request to create the index fail. I've updated my post with the index definition I used and results.


According to MSDOC the index describes and contains all data that can be searched. Every data field you want to search gets its own field in the search index. Each field also has a data type and different properties – as if the field is sortable or facetable. The index reflects the data you want to search without the unnecessary fields you do not need and is precisely customized for your search case.

Example request structure for a search index as below in vector search or semantic resources:
{
    "name": "my-index",
    "fields": [
        // define your fields here
    ],
    "vectorSearch": {
        "algorithmConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "my-hnsw-algorithm",
                "kind": "hnsw"
                // additional parameters
            }
        ]
    },
    "semantic": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "default",
                "prioritizedFields": {
                    "titleField": {"fieldName": "title"},
                    "contentFields": [{"fieldName": "content"}],
                    "keywordsField": {"fieldName": "keywords"}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}




Refer this MSDOC to   Create Or Update  , semantic capabilities and for Configuring  a vectorizer  using REST API

Problem elements are not created (e.g. vectorSearch profiles/vectorizer/algorithms/compression can be resloved adding vectorSearchProfile to the fileds
like this

 @{
            name = "chunk"
            type = "Collection(Edm.Single)"
            searchable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            dimensions = 1536
            vectorSearchProfile = "my-vector-profile"
        }



and configuring the   vectorSearch with  algorithms and   profiles.
For semantic configuration must have  following fileds : Title field,Content fields and Keyword fields   .Refer to this MSDOC for more details  about Configuring semantic  in  Azure AI Search.

In below example Title field is Hotel name ,Content fields is Description and Keyword fields is  Tags.

I refer this MSDOC to vector search in Azure AI Search .  Refer to this MSDOC to integrate vectorization for Azure AI Search and Data Plane.

The below PowerShell script creates an index for Azure Cognitive Search. The sample index is designed for a vector search capabilities and semantic configurations.

$body = @{
    name = $indexName
    fields = @(
        @{
            name = "HotelId"
            type = "Edm.String"
            searchable = $false
            filterable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $false
            facetable = $false
            key = $true
        },
        @{
            name = "HotelName"
            type = "Edm.String"
            searchable = $true
            filterable = $false
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $true
            facetable = $false
        },
        @{
            name = "HotelNameVector"
            type = "Collection(Edm.Single)"
            searchable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            dimensions = 1536
            vectorSearchProfile = "my-vector-profile"
        },
        @{
            name = "Description"
            type = "Edm.String"
            searchable = $true
            filterable = $false
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $false
            facetable = $false
        },
        @{
            name = "DescriptionVector"
            type = "Collection(Edm.Single)"
            searchable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            dimensions = 1536
            vectorSearchProfile = "my-vector-profile"
        },
        @{
            name = "Category"
            type = "Edm.String"
            searchable = $true
            filterable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $true
            facetable = $true
        },
        @{
            name = "Tags"
            type = "Collection(Edm.String)"
            searchable = $true
            filterable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $false
            facetable = $true
        },
        @{
            name = "Address"
            type = "Edm.ComplexType"
            fields = @(
                @{
                    name = "City"
                    type = "Edm.String"
                    searchable = $true
                    filterable = $true
                    retrievable = $true
                    sortable = $true
                    facetable = $true
                },
                @{
                    name = "StateProvince"
                    type = "Edm.String"
                    searchable = $true
                    filterable = $true
                    retrievable = $true
                    sortable = $true
                    facetable = $true
                }
            )
        },
        @{
            name = "Location"
            type = "Edm.GeographyPoint"
            searchable = $false
            filterable = $true
            retrievable = $true
            sortable = $true
            facetable = $false
        }
    )
    vectorSearch = @{
        algorithms = @(
            @{
                name = "my-hnsw-vector-config-1"
                kind = "hnsw"
                hnswParameters = @{
                    m = 4
                    efConstruction = 400
                    efSearch = 500
                    metric = "cosine"
                }
            },
            @{
                name = "my-hnsw-vector-config-2"
                kind = "hnsw"
                hnswParameters = @{
                    m = 4
                    metric = "euclidean"
                }
            },
            @{
                name = "my-eknn-vector-config"
                kind = "exhaustiveKnn"
                exhaustiveKnnParameters = @{
                    metric = "cosine"
                }
            }
        )
        profiles = @(
            @{
                name = "my-vector-profile"
                algorithm = "my-hnsw-vector-config-1"
            }
        )
    }
    // Add your configuration options on how to vectorize text vector queries.
    semantic = @{
        configurations = @(
            @{
                name = "my-semantic-config"
                prioritizedFields = @{
                    titleField = @{
                        fieldName = "HotelName"
                    }
                    prioritizedContentFields = @(
                        @{
                            fieldName = "Description"
                        }
                    )
                    prioritizedKeywordsFields = @(
                        @{
                            fieldName = "Tags"
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 

$response






Refer to MSDOC for integrating vectorization with models from Azure AI Studio.


Like I mentionned, if I add the field that uses the vectorSearchProfile the api call fails.
Here is the eror I get, I'll update the question with exactly what I pass in.
InvalidRequestParameter","message":"The request is invalid. Details: definition : The field 'text_vector' uses a vector search algorithm configuration '' which is not defined.","details":[{"code":"UnknownVectorAlgorithmConfiguration","message":"The field 'text_vector' uses a vector search algorithm configuration '' which is not defined. Parameters: definition"}]}}

To with field you added

I added the example with the vectorSearchField. I updated my semantic config but still the same error. Script fails before the index is created.
